# Pine script: Switch trendline based on if statement

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

How do I set my trendline color and plot based on an if statement i.e. if stock data is > 1 year then use trendline 1 else use trendline method 2:

```
trend_1 = sma(close, 15)
trend_2 = sma(close, 30)

bearish = true

for i = 0 to trendConfirmationLength - 1
    bearish := bearish and (close[i] < trend[i])

bullish = not bearish

// Set the color of the plot based on whether we are bullish (green) or not (red)
c = bullish ? color.green : color.red

// Plot the trend line
trend = 
if (len(close) > 252)
   trend_1
if (len(close) < 252)
   trend_2

trend_plot = plot(trend, title='Trend', color = c)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
trend_1 = sma(close, 15)
trend_2 = sma(close, 30)

float trend = na

if bar_index >= 252
    trend := trend_1
else
    trend := trend_2

bool foundBearish = false
bool foundBullish = false

for i = 0 to trendConfirmationLength - 1
    if close[i] < trend[i]
        foundBearish := true
    else if close[i] > trend[i]
        foundBullish := true

bullish = foundBullish and not foundBearish
bearish = foundBearish and not foundBullish
neutral = not bullish and not bearish

color c = na
if bullish
    c := color.green
else if bearish
    c := color.red
else if neutral
    c := color.blue

trend_plot = plot(trend, title='Trend', color = c)
```

If all closes within `trendConfirmationLength` are below `trend` then `foundBearish` will be true and `foundBullish` will be false (and vice versa). If both `foundBearsh` and `foundBullish` are true, it means we had closes both above and below `trend`.

Alternatively you could do this to keep the trend color until a new trend is formed rather than show a neutral color.

```
color c = na
if bullish
    c := color.green
else if bearish
    c := color.red

trend_plot = plot(trend, title='Trend', color = fixnan(c))
```

Comment: Sorry if I want to ammend an else if statement, to the following why do I still end up with error:

```
trend_1 = sma(close, 60)
trend_2 = sma(close, 30)
trend_3 = sma(close, 15)

if bar_index >= 252
    trend := trend_1
else if bar_index < 252 and >= 126
    trend := trend_2
else 
    trend := trend_3
```

Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

Comment: you forgot a `bar_index` from `else if bar_index < 252 and bar_index >= 126`